# php parsing strings and see if they are similars

Tags: php, string, parsing, function, matching

I am writing a function php which has to do something like this:

- we have two strings, ex: "**Bienvenue**" and "**Bienbenue**"
- the two string don't match with the php function strpos.
- but normally, the basic comportement of my function is to say, yes ok there is just one letter which differ between the two strings, so I return true. But I need some help for find an algorithm or an php function which exist?
- In this example: "**Bienvenue**" and "**Vienlpntw**"
- there is just "ien" which match the pattern, I have to see how many letters had matched and after that, comparate this number with the size of the word / pattern.
- So we have 9 / 3 = 3; this ratio is bad, so I return false.

  but in this example: "**interactivity**" and "**intevactizity**", we have "*inte*" "*acti*" and "*ity*"
  which are matching. so we have 11 of 13 letters that are corrects.
  So it's not easy to manage errors of letters ...

For resume, I am looking for a php function which can tell me if an entry can match or not with my pattern, return true or false respecting these points.

Comment: Whats the application of this? It smells of homework...

Comment: Homework I don't think so, it's just for upgrade my research engine of my website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in function, [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) to accomplish this. Make sure you check out the [notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php#101458) as well for some of the 'quirks'.

Based on your comments, you probably want to use something like [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP), which gets the longest common substring, and then divide it by string length and give it a threshold by which to return true or false

Comment: I dont know how works this algorithm but it's not that I am looking for. This algorithm doesn't take in consideration the place of the letters in the string

Comment: It's not just see if for example the letter 'a' is contained in the string 'salut', the letter 'a' have to be the second letter in the first string, u see what i mean ?

Comment: @Necko That is a matter of opinion, I would say `salut` and `ssalut` are pretty similar, but according to your algorithm they are not.

Comment: @jeroen Yes they are similar also. So the function have to return true in this case because :
salut is contained in 'salut'

Answer (score 1):

here a very simple example

```
function precisionMatch($string1, $string2, $precision = 0.6666666) {

    $matchCount = 0;
    $string1Length = strlen($string1);
    $string2Length = strlen($string2);
    for($i = 0; $i < $string1Length; $i++) {

        if ($i < $string2Length && $string1[$i] == $string2[$i]) {

            $matchCount++;
        }
    }

    return $matchCount / ($string1Length == 0 ? 1 : $string1Length) > $precision;
}
```